# Where should i store the external client DTOs of my microservice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, microservices, dto

I have a doubt about the architecture of the app I am working on. 
It is built like this following modules:

```
module-app
module-domain
module-rest
module-rest-api
module-rest-client
```

In the `module-rest-api` I store the `DTO`s of my controllers. But now i have to add others `DTO`s to call an external client.

So the question is, where do i have to implement those external DTO, in the `module-rest-api`or inside the `external client package` into the `module-app`?

I would appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: Make a jar for it and used it across your projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one answer here because where you put those DTO's very much depends on personal preference.

For example, you could have a module-dto. In the module-dto you could have a number of packages and divide them by purpose e.g.

```
com.mycompany.project.dto.outbound.   //for external requests
com.mycompany.project.dto.inbound.    //for incoming api requests
```

This way you can just import your dto module anywhere. I've always maintained my DTO's is a standalone module for this very reason that I can just use it then from anywhere then.